# Does imprinting occur at different life stages?

Tags: evolution, behaviour, life-history, sociality

For example, consider the offspring of a bird species. Can offspring get imprinted by other individuals of the same population at various life stages (e.g., hatchling, nestling, fledgeling, juvenile)?
If you have any literature, please send the links.